# How do I update an individual component using aurelia store?

Tags: html, typescript, aurelia, web-component

I'm using the aurelia-store plugin. I have this list, and it's generally rendering correctly, except enabled/disabled which is what I'm working on.

```
export interface State {
  readonly availableGames: AvailableGame[];
  readonly myGames: Game[];
}

export const initialState: State = {
  availableGames: [
    { name: 'Foo', added: false },
    { name: 'Bar', added: false },
  ],
  myGames: [],
};
```

`AvailableGames.html`

```html
<template>
  <require from="./game-add-button.html"></require>
  <div class="game-list">
    <ul class="list-group">
      <li repeat.for="game of state.availableGames">
        <game-add-button game.bind="game" on-add.call="addGameToMyList(game)"></game-add-button>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</template>
```

`AvailableGames`

```
import { autoinject } from 'aurelia-framework';
import { connectTo, Store } from 'aurelia-store';
import { Event } from '../Event';
import { State } from '../State';
import AvailableGame from './AvailableGame';
import Game from './Game';

@connectTo()
@autoinject()
export default class AvailableGames {

  readonly state!: State;

  constructor(private store: Store<State>) {
    this.store.registerAction(Event.ADD_GAME_TO_MY_LIST, (state, game) => this.onAddNewState(state, game));
  }

  async addGameToMyList(availableGame: AvailableGame): Promise<void> {
    const { added, ...game } = availableGame;
    return await this.store.dispatch(Event.ADD_GAME_TO_MY_LIST, game);
  }

  private onAddNewState(state: State, game: Game): State {
    return {
      ...state,
      myGames: [...state.myGames, game]
    };
  }
}
```

`game-add-button.html`

```html
<template bindable="game,onAdd" role="button">
  <button class="button ${game.added ? 'is-success' : ''}" click.trigger="onAdd(game)" disabled.bind="game.added">
    ${game.name}
  </button>
</template>
```

`GameAddButton.ts`

```
@customElement('game-add-button')
export default class GameAddButton {
  @bindable game!: AvailableGame;
  @bindable onAdd!: (game: AvailableGame) => void
}
```

everything seems to work, except when I click the button, the state update is not reflected in the UI. How do I change my code so that the buttons state is reflected?

Comment: What is state.availableGames referring to that you use in your repeat?

Comment: @zewa666 added info to question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know what your intention with the myGames array was, which you're pushing the selected game to in your action. But in your AvailableGames.html you're still iterating on availableGames and haven't modified it in your new state to say added: true for the selected game.

Comment: So the right answer is just to directly modify it? I guess I was assuming that there would be some magic use of the store plugin, or that perhaps I completely had the wrong design. The `myGames` array is going to be used in a subsequent view. I have questioned whether updating that available field is even the right decision. Basically I'm not convinced this is how I should be doing things.

Comment: I'd recommend taking a look at the samples repository mentioned in the official guide. E.g there is a todo app which demonstrates a similar behavior